# Kotlin (Flutter)- Remove Sticky notification for background service

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

I'm building an app that does some processing in the background.

This is my code:-

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
         .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)) 
         .setContentText("Welcome To TestApp") 
         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
    
    // startForeground(105, builder.setNotificationSilent().build())

    // Handler
    eventLoop = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            println("Inside Run.") // does not prints when `startForeground` is commented, and the code is broken.
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000) // Subsequent runs
        }
    }
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        handler.post(eventLoop) // first launch
    }

    return START_STICKY
}
```

The above code works fine when `startForeground` is not commented. This is the function that brings up the sticky notification. I read about it in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) and by the looks of it, I'm ok if my service is killed to reclaim more memory. I've my work manager set which automatically starts the service if killed.

However, when I comment it, the code breaks. The `run` function is not executed upon moving the app to the background or killing it or even if the notification bar is pulled down.

This is the exception which is thrown.

```
I/in.zoffers(20132): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
F/crash_dump64(21223): crash_dump.cpp:465] failed to attach to thread 567: Permission denied
D/AndroidRuntime(20132): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(20132): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(20132): Process: in.zoffers, PID: 20132
E/AndroidRuntime(20132): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{737e848 u0 in.zoffers/.AutoOffersService}
E/AndroidRuntime(20132):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2151)
E/AndroidRuntime(20132):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(20132):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
E/AndroidRuntime(20132):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
E/AndroidRuntime(20132):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(20132):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime(20132):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
W/MixpanelAPI.SysInfo(20132): Permission READ_PHONE_STATE not granted. Property $radio will not be available.
Lost connection to device.
```

What exactly is happening here?? Since, I'm ok with my service being killed upon memory management, I don't need `startForeground`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read about it in the docs and by the looks of it, I'm ok if my service is killed to reclaim more memory

It will be killed in 60 seconds on Android 8.0+, unless you make it  a foreground service with `startForeground()`.

> What exactly is happening here?

You called `startForegroundService()` to start the service. This means that you are required to call `startForeground()` within the ANR time period (~15 seconds IIRC). If you do not want to call `startForeground()`, do not use `startForegroundService()` to start the service.

Comment: What are the other ways in which a service can be started, other than startForegroundService?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: The original way to start a service is via `startService()` (a method on `Context`).

Comment: But that does not work for version >= 26.

Comment: ```Beginning with SDK Version Build.VERSION_CODES.O, apps targeting SDK Version Build.VERSION_CODES.O or higher are not allowed to start background services from the background. See Background Execution Limits for more details.
```

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: It works fine if you are starting the background service from the foreground, such as from an activity, though the background service will only run for a minute.

Comment: Got it. However, I believe if I want to start the background service via the work manager or some silent notification, then `startService()` wont work for version >=26. Right?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: Correct. If you are already using `WorkManager`, it is unclear why you need a service of any type. But, if you are going to start a service from the background, that service needs to be a foreground service. So, you need to use `startForegroundService()`, and you need to uncomment your `startForeground()` line.